# Renumbering dynamically added text boxes

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

i have the below code which dynamically adds and deletes a text box to a form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
var str = '<div id="my{0}Div"><textarea id="corrective{0}" name="corrective{0}"  rows="12" cols="50" class="field textarea small"></textarea><span class="link" id="delete{0}Row">Remove This</span></div>';

<cfif thisInstance.recommendationCorrectiveAction.RecordCount>
var i = <cfoutput>#thisInstance.recommendationCorrectiveAction.RecordCount#</cfoutput>+1;
<cfelse>
var i = 2;                              
</cfif>

 function addRow() {
    updateStr = jQuery.format(str, i);                              
    $(updateStr).appendTo("#MyRecommends");

     // add the click handler for the delete link
    $('#delete'+i+'Row').click(deleteRow);

   // reset the corrective action count
    updateCorrectiveActionCount = parseInt(objForm.correctiveActionCount.getValue())+1;
    objForm.correctiveActionCount.setValue(updateCorrectiveActionCount);  
  i++;
 }

function deleteRow() {
    var parentID = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');            
    $('#MyRecommends #'+parentID).remove();          
    // reset the corrective action count
    updateCorrectiveActionCount = parseInt(objForm.correctiveActionCount.getValue())-1;
    objForm.correctiveActionCount.setValue(updateCorrectiveActionCount);
    i--;  
    }


    $("#add").click(addRow);
});
```

This works fine if I add and remove the text box serially. But if i add two text boxes say tb2 and tb3 and press the "Remove This" link for tb2; although the value of i above reduces to 2 but I get an error saying "Element corrective2 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope.  <br>The error occurred on line 351."

I need a solution where each time a text box is added or removed the entire series gets renumbered, or any better solution.

Comment: What have you tried as far as renumbering them goes? This is more a JQuery question than a ColdFusion question, as the renumbering needs to take place on the client, and ColdFusion plays no part in that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about renumbering the elements. One of my colleagues suggested it, but i'm not totally sure how or where to do it.

Comment: Which part of it? How to change an element's ID? How to loop? How to use JQuery or Javascript *at all*? You're probably being premature asking a question on S/O if you don't know *anything* about how to do this. You kinda need to demonstrate *some* effort in solving a problem before soliciting people to help you. What research into this have you done? Do you understand that code that you posted? Not just the end result, but how it works to get there?

Comment: @AdamCameron I understand the above code, but i'm not sure how to loop so that i can renumber the elements in the div. I need something like a for loop in the deleteRow function which will work only if parentID is less than i(i think). I am very new to jQuery and i don't have knowledge of all the functions, and i wrote the deleteRow function myself, and thought it worked well until someone pointed out the issue mentioned above. That's the reason why i came to stackoverflow for help.